# ComboBox style Issue with Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem with style comboBox the items after selected not shown correctly I tried to find the problem with Flat blue Style, Please advise
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W9Md.png)

Answer (score 0):

Customize the `ComboBoxPopup` UIID to match your desired look see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html

Comment: **Thank you for your response**